# Will using an array for map tiles in a web game in this manner be too resource intensive?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm working on a PHP-based browser RPG in which the player moves on a grid map.  My maps are defined via a two dimensional matrix with each value being a 21 character string of letters and numbers.  This string is an encoded value that tells the game what happens on that tile, and it gives me a wide range of options for additional features in the future.  I considered using just integers for this value, but I decided that I wanted to retain some readability of the maps so I could still eyeball files.

I currently output the map with a map creation script into a .csv file, then the player movement class opens that map file, finds the players current coordinates and moves in the direction that the player indicated.

My current map sizes top out at 200x300 tiles, each tile containing that grid's value (AAAAB111CCC2222223333); however, I would like to keep the ability to make these up to 1000x1000 in the future (larger than that would likely see maps for regions of an overall world).

I store the player coordinates in a user status database, so I will just read lines of the .csv map that were within the range of the player's movement and prevent the entire map from being loaded into a variable every time a player moves.  However, this could still be an 11x1000 grid with those 21 character codes in each tile.  After finding the result of each movement I will unset the array.

Even with my precautionary measures, I am concerned that this will this become too much of a resource burden in the future if many users are playing at the same time and I wonder if I should store map information in a database instead.

The rest of my user and game data is stored in a few large databases.  When I started working on my game, I didn't believe that these map grid data sets were complex enough to warrant putting them into their own database, and it seemed like using an array for movement would be easy (`$location[$x][$y]`). However, now I'm wondering if using .csv files will hurt my performance or not.

Comment: I will look for an specific database that suits your needs. For example, redis is very fast with its key-value pattern. I've done some map things like yours and every tile can be seen as a key (tile_XX_YY) and the value is your 21 codes, or even more things. That way you will also have everything persistent at any time and also if the game scales, you will be able to scale the dbs because redis was built to be also scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file will definitely be more work from a csv, especially if you increase the map size.  The problem I see with taking only portions of the csv for loading is you still have to parse the data to get to the players x,y coordinates.  Following (or at the same time) parsing each string to find out if it is included in the near player set.

And as you say, you are expecting more players as time goes on.  The amount of reads drive reads needed to open/parse the file would grow quickly and cause problems unless you had some form of caching available.

So, I would say go with a database, and the sooner the better. As yes, using a csv will hurt performance.